# Streamlined way to sort thru servers and determine the fastest ping

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, command, batch-processing

I am trying to determine the fastest ping rate out of a number of servers on the network. The number of servers could be as many as a couple dozen. I do have script as shown below that will sort thru a few at the moment and it works well, but I am looking for a more elegant way to do it. The list of servers could be stored in a text file as well. Actually a text file for the server names may be easier to maintain since they may change over time.

EDIT: This script also does not handle if the server is offline, so I could accidently end up with a offline server being listed as the fastest ping.

```
SET SERVER_A=MEDUBNA2
SET SERVER_B=HANSECAD2
SET SERVER_C=MEINWESSFS01
SET SERVER_D=MEAUHWC01

for /f "tokens=2 delims==," %%a in ('ping %SERVER_A% -n 1 -w 1000') do SET MINSERVER_A=%%a
for /f "tokens=2 delims==," %%b in ('ping %SERVER_B% -n 1 -w 1000') do SET MINSERVER_B=%%b
for /f "tokens=2 delims==," %%c in ('ping %SERVER_C% -n 1 -w 1000') do SET MINSERVER_C=%%c
for /f "tokens=2 delims==," %%d in ('ping %SERVER_D% -n 1 -w 1000') do SET MINSERVER_D=%%d

SET MINSERVER_A=%MINSERVER_A:~0,-2%
SET MINSERVER_B=%MINSERVER_B:~0,-2%
SET MINSERVER_C=%MINSERVER_C:~0,-2%
SET MINSERVER_D=%MINSERVER_D:~0,-2%


if %MINSERVER_A% lss %MINSERVER_B% (
    SET FASTESTSERVERGROUP1=%SERVER_A%
    ) else (
    SET FASTESTSERVERGROUP1=%SERVER_B%
)

if %MINSERVER_C% lss %MINSERVER_D% (
    SET FASTESTSERVERGROUP2=%SERVER_C%
    ) else (
    SET FASTESTSERVERGROUP2=%SERVER_D%
)

if %FASTESTSERVERGROUP1% lss %FASTESTSERVERGROUP2% (
    SET FASTESTSERVEROVERALL=%FASTESTSERVERGROUP1%
    ) else (
    SET FASTESTSERVEROVERALL=%FASTESTSERVERGROUP2%
)

echo %SERVER_A%: %MINSERVER_A%
echo %SERVER_B%: %MINSERVER_B%
echo %SERVER_C%: %MINSERVER_C%
echo %SERVER_D%: %MINSERVER_D%

echo Fastest Server Group 1: %FASTESTSERVERGROUP1%
echo Fastest Server Group 2: %FASTESTSERVERGROUP2%


:: Ultimate goal is to determine the fastest server out of the list.
echo Fastest Server Overall: %FASTESTSERVEROVERALL%
```

Comment: You can use a `FOR /F` command to read a file with a list of server names.

Comment: I don't understand why the first two servers comprise Group 1 and the next two Group 2. If the goal is to determine the fastest server, the groups dont matters. Otherwise, explain how the servers placed in a text file must be divided in groups... Two by two perhaps?

Comment: The servers don't need to be in groups. I only put them in groups for a little cleaner process of elimination, because I didn't want to nest if statements within if statements since i don't know a cleaner way of doing this. The way i did it was much like brackets in a basketball tournament.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is create a couple of nested `FOR` commands to read the server list. Then ping the server. Manipulate the output so that it only has numbers.  Then compare the number to the current fastest.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "ms=10000"
set "fastest="
REM Read the server list
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (serverlist.txt) DO (
    REM read the ping results
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==," %%H in ('ping %%G -n 1 -w 1000 ^|find /i "minimum"') do (
        REM Manipulate the ping result so that it is only a number
        for /f "delims=m " %%I in ("%%H") do (
            REM Compare the ping result to the current fastest time.
            IF %%I LSS !ms! (
                set "fastest=%%G"
                set "ms=%%I"
            )
        )
    )
)
echo Fastest Server is: %fastest%
pause
```

Comment: I really appreciate what you did here. I have a concern here regarding the ping command and the language of the users machine that will be running this script. Knowing that this script will be ran globally, is there a way to make it so it not English dependent. I am afraid that if you perform "find" on a keyword, it may not be found due to the machine being in Russian, Chinese or Portuguese for example.

Comment: @Bill That is kind of the holy grail. I would have to see if the output has some consistency.  For example does PING output 3 equals symbols and 2 commas on that line.  If it does, then you could use the `FINDSTR` command to match on that to get the correct line.

Comment: @Bill, have someone with a different language test this: Replace the `FIND` logic with this `FINDSTR` logic: `findstr /R /C:".*=.*,.*=.*,.*=.*[^,]$"`

Comment: @Bill the `FINDSTR` only takes care of making sure it grabs the last line only.  We would still need to strip off the milliseconds abbreviation.  We would not know how many characters in each language the abbreviation is.

Comment: Happy New Years... I have done some research regarding ping results and result formats based on the users language/local settings. Based on what I could see, it looks like all languages use "ms" for milliseconds abbreviation, its just formatted one of two ways "100ms" or "100 ms". So I was wondering if these two formats will both be covered in the code you provided?

Take a look at this, I found this useful.
https://www.itefix.net/content/problem-checkwinpingexe

Comment: @Bill what happened when you tested it?

Comment: Unfortunately its next to impossible for me to identify a user with a different language. I have test what you have provided many times and everything works great on the English machines, which is probably 95% of my approx. 3000 machine global user base. I will try to pin point someone.